# to filter multiple rows on button click - laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, datatables, laravel-8

I have a table with student details and I want to filter each row. Like when "ID" and "Name" is entered and filter button is clicked the row with that details has to be displayed. I tried using JavaScript it does filter single rows separately. Is there any approach where I can filter them together or how can I write one single function for separate filter textboxes.

[image]

```html
<thead>
  <th>
    <input
      type="text"
      id="myInput1"
      class="form-control filter-input"
      placeholder="Search by ID..."
      data-column="0"
    />
  </th>

  <th>
    <input
      type="text"
      id="myInput"
      onkeyup="myFunction()"
      class="form-control filter-input"
      placeholder="Search by Name..."
      data-column="1"
    />
  </th>

  <th>
    <input
      type="text"
      id="myInput2"
      onkeyup="myFunction2()"
      class="form-control filter-input"
      placeholder="Search by YOP..."
      data-column="3"
    />
  </th>

  <th>
    <input
      type="text"
      id="myInput3"
      onkeyup="myFunction3()"
      class="form-control filter-input"
      placeholder="Search by Status..."
      data-column="4"
    />
  </th>

  <th>
    <button
      onclick="myFunctionID()"
      class="btn btn-success btn-block mobile-width"
    >
      <i class="fa fa-filter"></i> Filter
    </button>
  </th>
</thead>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue

    input = document.getElementById("myInput")
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase()
    table = document.getElementById("myTable")
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")

    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
      td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1]

      if (td) {
        txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText

        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          tr[i].style.display = ""
        } else {
          tr[i].style.display = "none"
        }
      }
    }
  }

  function myFunctionID() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue

    input = document.getElementById("myInput1")
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase()
    table = document.getElementById("myTable")
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")

    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
      td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0]

      if (td) {
        txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          tr[i].style.display = ""
        } else {
          tr[i].style.display = "none"
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I have used same function and have changed only the array index for each column.

Comment: best way use datatable,js sample : https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html

Comment: my toggle button doesnot work inside datatable.

Comment: why ? solving this problem easier than make filtering table - this comment is a suggestion

Comment: So, you want to filter on keyup or on button click?

Comment: with great trouble I made it, I don't want to go back there again... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74488254/toggle-button-doesnt-work-inside-datatable-in-laravel

Comment: @Sonu Bamniya - on button click, I just tried it with keyup to see if it works and it does. I want it like.. to fill details from each row and then click filter.

Comment: So you want to call API or refresh page with different query params, or just filter from the data that you have on screen?

Comment: jst filter the data on screen.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63410300/javascript-filter-in-table-by-multiple-rows  This helped.